# How to customize HTML/CSS tooltips?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What's the best way to customize HTML/CSS tooltips? (I mean an easy, cross-browser solution.)

I need to reduce the fade-in delay and change the style. (Also, could you suggest a good jQuery plug-in for it?)

Comment: If anyone coming across this is considering non-JS/jQuery solutions, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17391243/983430) to a related question. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4k90opzv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/) and the older version, [Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) before and they work pretty well in all browsers (even IE6!).

The documentation is really good and you can configure the fade in/out delay: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show

Style reference: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#styling

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could get the title attribute of an object and add an element with that value. There is a little gem from `jQuery: Novice to Ninja (SitePoint 2010)`. I am unsure if I am allowed to post it here, although the the code itself [has been made public on sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2010/03/11/all-scripts-used-in-jquery-novice-to-ninja-are-now-free-to-download/) by the authors. Download the archive and see chapter_05\17_simple_tooltips. It's 25 lines long and works great.

Comment: I found this comment, and was interested in other code examples. SitePoint's github: https://github.com/spbooks

Answer (score 0):

This is another tooltip plugin worth looking at, http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin