# Tooltip with HTML content without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, tooltip

There are plenty of JavaScript-based libraries that show tooltips when you hover your mouse over a certain area of a web page. Some are rather plain, some allow the tooltip to display HTML content styled with CSS.

But is there a way to show a styled tooltip without using JavaScript? If you just use the `title` attribute, tags are not processed (e.g. `foo<br />bar` doesn't produce a line break). I'm looking for a solution that allows one to display styled HTML content without using any JavaScript.

Comment: Use the title attribute.

Comment: may be with `hidden` elements and show them with `hover`

Comment: @Nile: It doesn't work. For example, if I put the "<br />" tag, the tooltip shows "foo<br />bar", you know what I mean?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I have made a little example using `css`

```css
.hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  /* hide and position tooltip */
  top: -10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.hover:hover .tooltip {
  /* display tooltip on hover */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">hover
  <div class="tooltip">asdadasd
  </div>
</div>
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/8gC3D/471/

Comment: This doesn't work very well. If you hover `.tooltip` without hovering `.hover` the tooltip will come up. Therefore I suggested add `visibility: hidden/visible` to avoid this.

Comment: Wait, is this really possible?? I was expecting a bunch of "nope, you can't" answers when I came from google, but instead I got wiser. Thank you sir koningdavid. :)
Which version of HTML/CSS is this? Only CSS3 or have it been around for ages? Any downsides to this compared to Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: @Kenneth_hj Hi Kenneth, the transition effect is CSS3, in older browser it will work, just without the transition!

Comment: @pzin How could hovering tooltip make the tooltip to appear? The CSS rule is: .hover:hover .tooltip, so it's /hover/ that must be hovered.

Comment: Apart from that, when you add visibility, the tooltip stops working on Chrome on Win 7 (I didn't check other browsers).

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski if you hover a child then the parent is hovered too. In this case the child was outside the parent, but it's still its child. Setting just an `opacity` will not make the child to disappear (and you could hover it) like `visibility` does.

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski that's because of trying to animate everything instead of just animate `opacity`: http://jsfiddle.net/8gC3D/412

Comment: I see... thank you for explaining. But anyway, rules with `visibility` didn't work for me on Chrome Win7...

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski Yep, I noticed that, it used to work but no longer does! I removed visibility, thanks for you suggestion

Comment: Nice, but how can we exclude .tooltip from the hover area of .hover?

Comment: I've been using this for a while - still think it's a very elegant solution - but came across an issue with handling overlapping tooltips today, so posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258565/css-tooltip-issue-with-overlapping-tooltips).

Comment: As @AmosM.Carpenter pointed, you need to add:
`visibility: hidden;`  to  `.tooltip` class and
`visibility: visible;`  to  `.hover:hover .tooltip` class. 

Otherwise the tooltip will show up when you hover `.hover` but also when you hover `.tooltip` which will cause an unwanted behaviour (specially if your tooltip area isn't small)

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the OP's question - I was expecting to see a tooltip that _contained_ HTML.  The answer uses CSS to style the tooltip's appearance in it's entirety, but you couldn't have (for example) tables, images, hyperlinks, individual words bold-face etc.

Answer (score 18):

Using the **title** attribute:

```html
<a href="#" title="Tooltip here">Link</a>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it'll only hold text, not html content like OP wants.

Comment: There's also a long pause between when you hover, and when the content appears. I think a lot of people will move on before it appears, because they don't know to wait.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to koningdavid's, but works on display:none and block, and adds additional styling.

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  /*  DO NOT include below two lines, as they were added so that the text that
        is hovered over is offset from top of page*/
  top: 10em;
  left: 10em;
  /* if want hover over icon instead of text based, uncomment below */
  /*    background-image: url("../images/info_tooltip.svg");
            /!* width and height of svg *!/
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;*/
}


/* hide tooltip */

div.tooltip span {
  display: none;
}


/* show and style tooltip */

div.tooltip:hover span {
  /* show tooltip */
  display: block;
  /* position relative to container div.tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  /* prettify */
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ebf4fb;
  border: 0.1em solid #b7ddf2;
  /* round the corners */
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  /* prevent too wide tooltip */
  max-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  hover_over_me
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis purus dui. Sed at orci. </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point that you switched from `opacity:0` to `display:none` . Otherwise, you get the strange effect of seeing the tooltip when hovering around the element, as you are hovering on the tooltip, even if this is not visible.

Answer (score 9):

This one is very interesting,

> HTML and CSS only

```css
.help-tip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #BCDBEA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before {
  content: '?';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.help-tip:hover span {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.help-tip span {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #1E2021;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: -4px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #1E2021;
  left: 10px;
  top: -12px;
}

.help-tip span:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="help-tip">
     <span > This is the inline help tip! </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 7):

Pure CSS:

```css
.app-tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.app-tooltip:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  background-color: rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 2;
}

.app-tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: -16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.9) transparent;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.app-tooltip:hover:after,
.app-tooltip:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div href="#" class="app-tooltip" data-title="Your message here"> Test here</div>
```

Comment: Question is about showing HTML content in tooltip; your answer shows textual content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the title attribute, e.g. if you want to have a Tooltip over a text, just make:

```html
<span title="This is a Tooltip">This is a text</span>
```

Comment: "Nice idea, but it'll only hold text, not html content like OP wants."

Answer (score 2):

Another similar way to do it with CSS:

```css
#img {  }
#img:hover {visibility:hidden}
#thistext {font-size:22px;color:white }
#thistext:hover {color:black;}
#hoverme {width:50px;height:50px;}

#hoverme:hover { 
background-color:green;
position:absolute ;
left:300px;
top:100px;
width:40%;
height:20%;
}
```

```html
<p id="hoverme"><img id="img" src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/l/o/lol-cat.jpg"></img><span id="thistext">LOCATZ!!!!</span></p>
```

Try the [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FdBu7/)

Here are some links about transitions and other ways to do it:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-show-and-hide/

Comment: It doesn't work well on Chrome/Win7 - the images are blinking/flipping

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for this:

https://gist.github.com/BryanMoslo/808f7acb1dafcd049a1aebbeef8c2755

The element recibes a "tooltip-title" attribute with the tooltip text and it is displayed with CSS on hover, I prefer this solution because I don't have to include the tooltip text as a HTML element!

```
#HTML
<button class="tooltip" tooltip-title="Save">Hover over me</button>

#CSS

body{
    padding: 50px;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:before {
    content: attr(tooltip-title);
    min-width: 54px;
    background-color: #999999;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 9px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -42px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -27px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999 transparent transparent;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover:before,
.tooltip:hover:after{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to place the code here in a code tag as well, just in case something ever happens to the link, and just to make it more readily available on this site.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Mark the hover site for the tooltip with a div of class tipSite */
.tipSite {
    position:relative; /* Make tipSite the parent of the triggers and tipText */
    display:inline-block;
    height:1rem;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.leftTrigger,.rightTrigger {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%; height:1rem;
    }
.leftTrigger {left:0px}
.rightTrigger {left:50%}

.tipText {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    visibility:hidden; /* To avoid flashing of tipText */
    min-width:7rem; max-width:14rem;
    padding:.75rem;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ffd;
    color:#000;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:.25rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .2s;
    }

/* Animate tip into view on mouse hover */
.leftTrigger:nth-child(1):hover ~ .tipText {
    left:0px; transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(calc(-100% - .25rem));
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
    }
.rightTrigger:nth-child(2):hover ~ .tipText {
    left:calc(100% + .5rem); transform:translateY(calc(-100% - .25rem));
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
    }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br>

This example shows how to create tooltips using CSS only. The user indicates where
the tooltip should show by where they click the target text or block. This example
only shows tooltips in two directions rather than four. For best results, view in full screen.
<br><br>

This is before text, <div class=tipSite>this is the trigger<div
    class="leftTrigger"></div>
    <div class="rightTrigger"></div>
    <div class=tipText>Short tip.</div></div>, and this is after text.<br><br>
```