# Html tags inside of double quote

Tags: html, bold

I need to **bold** the words inside of double quotes.

```
title="Character needs to be bold"
```

When i put `<b></b>` inside of title's double quote. it just displays them as it is.

So, Is there any way i can bold the characters inside the double quotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to style a title? (and with CSS or js?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383148/is-it-possible-to-style-a-title-and-with-css-or-js)

Comment: Answer is NO, you cannot do it with HTML

Comment: Yes, you can. But not with the regular title attribute.

Comment: For simple bold or italic, you can cheat... [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E96dW/). Not that I would recommend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way depending on the node you are using the '`title`' attribute under. See if it has a 'format' attribute as by default the title is set to 'text'. If so, set the `format="html"`, then you will be able to use `&lt;b&gt;` within your title.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to markup the text inside a title attribute? Because that's not going to work, you'll have to resort to some kind of extended tooltip solution (can be js, but there's also ways to do it with just html/css).

See this question:
[Tooltip with HTML content without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391194/tooltip-with-html-content-without-javascript)

<strike>Some more context would be appreciated though, just the title attribute doesn't give us much information</strike>

Title was edited to give context, my answer remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cannot format the string, that is used as the title of a html document. That ist the String, that will get the titel of the tab or window of the browser etc.

If you have a html-entity, that needs formatting, you can format the whole thing with `style="your css style"`, or other css integration. If you have a switch of formatting inside one html entity, you schould look after dividing it up into multiple entities or using another aproach. Do you have a complete example?

cheers,
 nx

Answer (score -3):

use < b > Character needs to be bold < / b>

no spaces in between the b and the symbols