# How to create CSS menu like Tooltip

Tags: html, css

I want to create CSS menu like tool-tip.
Please see attached image for exact what I want.
[image]

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? could you post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried some Jquery code but didn't get proper output.

Comment: Just add the code :P Here on stackoverflow we usually don't help out unless you show some code which worked or that did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tooltip with HTML content without JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391194/tooltip-with-html-content-without-javascript)

Comment: Without your HTML this is impossible to answer, there are also several questions already asking for similar things which a simple google search will give you.

Comment: Check http://www.designer-daily.com/jquery-prototype-mootool-tooltips-12632

Answer (score -3):

```
.tooltip-block:hover:after{
    border: 1px solid #fc0;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    background: #fffea1;
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    top: -26px;
}
```

Try  this on hover it might be helpful

Comment: Not exactly what the user is asking for. The request **appears** to be a generated *menu* that appears **like** a tooltip. Without the OP's code, it's practically impossible to provide a relevant answer,