# Show in tooltip a part of html page between two anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, anchor

Given an html page with several anchors defined. Is there a way to show in tooltip part of this page between two specified anchors? And, how?

You can assume the html page is something like this:

```
<body>
  <div>this is some text with tooltip when hovering</div>
  <a name="a1"></a>
  ....
  <a name="a2"></a>
  ....
  <a name="a3"></a>
  ....
  <a name="a4"></a>
</body>
```

So I want to hover on the div and see in the tooltip an html page between the two anchors a2 and a3.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391194/tooltip-with-html-content-without-javascript) gives a good way to show without using javascript, but just html and css. I would really prefer not using javascript, but please feel free to use it if that can greatly ease the task, and if you do so, please use no more libs other than jQuery.

Comment: it would be very complicated to have elements all over the page moving a `div` around without javascript imo.

Comment: It's a bit hard to grasp what you exactly want to achieve, especially since you already linked to a solution that doesn't uses javascript.

Comment: @brod sure, then just use javascript.

Comment: @MathiasW Using javascript is totally fine, as long as tooltip by hovering shows the content between a2 and a3.